# Disabling hover options for sliders in metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, slider, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a simple metro app in C# which uses sliders. The problem is that sliders change the foreground color, when the pointer is over it. How can I disable it? This is very annoying, because it destroys my visual concept of the application.

```
<Slider x:Name="SlidProgress" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-3,0,80" Grid.Row="2"     VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1920" Height="58" Foreground="#FF0BA4C4" IsRightTapEnabled="False"  ValueChanged="SlidProgress_ValueChanged" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="SlidProgress_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="SlidProgress_ManipulationCompleted" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize the `Slider`'s style. Below given is default style. You just need to comment out `PointerOver` visual state. **This solution is for Win8 apps**. Let me of you want for 8.1 or 8.

```
<Style TargetType="Slider">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyle">
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
          </Grid.Resources>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalInlineTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalInlineTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteVertical" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackVertical" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="17" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="32" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="1" />
            <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalBorder" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
            <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalBorder" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteVertical" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackVertical" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you are using more than one `Slider` and want to remove `PointerOver` effect in all, you don't need to create custom style but change the following SolidColorBrush key's values to transparent or any relevant color.

- SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush
- SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush
- SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush
- SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush

e.g.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
```